# Adding new terminal shell to VS Code

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I downloaded the [cmder](https://cmder.net/) shell and would like to integrate it with VS Code and use it as one of the terminals.

In VS Code, when I go to **View->Command Pallette**, and then type **Terminal: Select Default Shell**, I am promoted with a drop-down list that looks like the following

[image]

I would like to have a fourth option, for **Cmder**. So the list would include "**Command Prompt**, **PowerShell**, **Git Bash**, and **Cmder**". How do I add this option?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Seamless-VS-Code-Integration

Comment: @AkashBhave - Thanks. But that does not add **Cmder** as a new option, but rather change the **Command Prompt** to **Cmder**. It is not solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below link :
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

You need to edit the terminal integrated path in settings.json file to which ever thing you want it to compile it with

[image]
[image]